# How to find duplicates in associated fields in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I have table in postgresql that has the following values:

```
KEY VALNO
1   a1
2   x1
3   x2
4   a3
5   a1
6   x2
7   a4
8   a5
9   x6
4   x7
7   a6
```

KEY expects unique values, but there are duplicates (4,7). VALNO should have a unique KEY assigned to them, but same VALNO had used multiple KEY (a1 used both 1 & 5, x2 used both 3 & 6).

I tried the following sql to find duplicates, but could not succeed.

```
select KEY, VALNO from mbs m1
where (select count(*) from mbs m2
where m1.KEY = m2.KEY) > 1
order by KEY
```

Is there a better way to find same VALNO's have used different KEYS, and same KEY's have used different VALNO's?

ie

### Duplicate VALNO

```
KEY VALNO
1   a1
5   a1
3   x2
6   x2
```

### Duplicate KEY

```
KEY VALNO
4   x7
7   a6
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `VALNO` duplicate records, we can use `COUNT` as an analytic function:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY VALNO) cnt
    FROM mbs
)

SELECT "KEY", VALNO
FROM cte
WHERE cnt > 1;
```

The logic for the `KEY` duplicate query is almost identical, except that we can use this for the count definition:

```
COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY "KEY") cnt
```